# Loop Block with execution doesn't persist

Tags: postgresql, functions, plpgsql

I need to iterate over a result set and update records from the data.  I am using an anonymous block but the information does not persist.

Like this...

```
do $$ 
declare dados Record; 
begin 
   for dados in 
        select 
           vd."Id"
        from "Vendas" vd 
           inner join "ItensVendas" iv on iv."VendaId" = vd."Id" 
        where vd."Especie" = 'NFE' and coalesce(vd."ClienteId", 0) = 0 and iv."CodCFOP" in (5949, 5927) 
        group by vd."ChaveNFE", vd."Id", vd."DataCadastro" 
   loop 
        execute format('update "Vendas" set "EhConsumoProprio" = true where "Id" = %L', dados."Id"); 
   end loop; 
end $$;
```

And again...

```
do $$
declare dados Record;
declare cmd varchar(300);
begin
    for dados in 
        select
            vd."ChaveNFE",
            vd."Id",
            vd."DataCadastro"
        from
            "Vendas" vd
        inner join "ItensVendas" iv on
            iv."VendaId" = vd."Id"
        where
            vd."Especie" = 'NFE'
            and coalesce(vd."ClienteId",0)= 0
            and iv."CodCFOP" in (5949, 5927)
        group by vd."ChaveNFE",
                 vd."Id",
                 vd."DataCadastro" 
    loop
        raise notice '%',dados."Id";
        update "Vendas" set "EhConsumoProprio"=true where "Id"=dados."Id"; -- It don't persists
        cmd := format('update "Vendas" set "EhConsumoProprio"=true where "Id"=%L', dados."Id");
        raise notice '%', cmd;
            execute cmd; -- It don't persists
    end loop;
end $$;
```

Comment: Why PL/pgSQL and a loop? That can be done much more efficiently using a single UPDATE statement? But if the update doesn't "persist", maybe you turned off autocommit and simply forgot to `commit` the changes?

Comment: why do I need to put this in a migration of the entity framework to run across multiple databases. When I use commit manually I have... ERROR:  cannot begin/end transactions in PL/pgSQL

Comment: You need a commit **after** the do block - but again: you don't need PL/pgSQL for this at all. A simple UPDATE will work just fine.

Comment: It is true. It would be best to just use a simple update.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO just a single `UPDATE` can solve your issue. Something like this:

```
UPDATE "Vendas"
   SET "EhConsumoProprio" = TRUE
  FROM "ItensVendas"
 WHERE "ItensVendas"."VendaId" = "Vendas"."Id"
   AND "Vendas"."Especie" = 'NFE'
   AND "Vendas"."ClienteId" IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 0
   AND "ItensVendas"."CodCFOP" IN (5949, 5927);
```

Comment: `"Vendas"."ClienteId" IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 0` in a `WHERE` clause (where only `true` matters) is an expensive way of saying `"Vendas"."ClienteId" = 0`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter why is more expensive? The idea is deal with NULLs correctly. The original SQL did it using COALESCE function:  `coalesce(vd."ClienteId",0)= 0`

Comment: ... which is not the same. The original translates to `(vd."ClienteId" = 0 OR vd."ClienteId" IS NULL)` or `(vd."ClienteId" <> 0) IS NOT TRUE`. Your translation is incorrect *and* inefficient, no offence.

Comment: oops... you're correct... I'm completely mislead... the Op want to return all records where `vd."ClienteId" = 0 OR vd."ClienteId" IS NULL` using the COALESCE. Sorry about the noise.